# Filter WP REST API by taxonomy value (value1, value2, value3 etc...)

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I'm trying to filter my Custom post type taxonomy by values, but I haven't had any success.

I wondered if anyone else knew how to you'd go about doing this, or maybe I'm taking the wrong approach here?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you might have more success over on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can pass tax_query in your post query like this:

```
$tax_query[] =  array(
'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
'field' => 'tag_ID', // Filter by Texonomy field name tag_ID
'terms' => $termID, // your texonomy by which you want to filter
);
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'product',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'tax_query'     => $tax_query,
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
```

Also you can filter by taxonomy slug:-

```
$tax_query[] =  array(
'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
'field' => 'slug',
'terms' => $slugID
```

);

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to filter your custom post type by taxonomy term value? For example you have a post type "book" and a taxonomy "book_cat", and you want to get all book from a particular book_cat, is that right?

### WP REST API support filter by taxonomy term IDs natively.

You can juste make a GET request like that

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/book?book_cat=20
```

If you need to select more than one term, separate them with a comma.

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/book?book_cat=20,21,22
```

(`https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/<post_type>?<taxonomy_name>=<term_id>,<term_id>`)

that's it

edit:  actually you cant filter post type by term slug, you need to use id

If you need to get term_id by term_slug you can do like that:

```php
$term = get_term_by('slug', 'my-term-slug', 'my_taxonomy')
$term_id = $term->term_id;
```

### You can use custom filter to use term slug as parameter

If you really need to use slug as url parameter you can add a custom filter, take a look to [rest_{$this->post_type}_query hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/)

You can do something like that:

```php
/**
 * Filter book post type by book_cat slug
 *
 * @param array $args
 * @param WP_Rest_Request $request
 * @return array $args
 */
function filter_rest_book_query( $args, $request ) { 
    $params = $request->get_params(); 
    if(isset($params['book_cat_slug'])){
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'book_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => explode(',', $params['book_cat_slug'])
            )
        );
    }
    return $args; 
}   
// add the filter 
add_filter( "rest_book_query", 'filter_rest_book_query', 10, 2 );
```

and then

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/book?book_cat_slug=slug01,slug02
```

Comment: This almost does it, but I don't understand what adding the terms does. I'm trying to get everything within that post type, filtered by one or more genres (in my case).
I've got this currently.

/wp-json/wp/v2/bands?Jazz

Comment: bands is a post type ? actually you cant filter post type by term slug, you need to use id: like /wp-json/wp/v2/bands?genre=12
I edit my answer to show you how to get term id by term slug